# Retrieving single record from each group in group_by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to get the employees of a business with the highest points in placements for each month.

The schema looks like this:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :employees
 has_many :placements, through: :employees

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name
 belongs_to :business
 has_many :placements

class Placement < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :month, :employee_id, :points
 belongs_to :employee
```

I have tried the following:

```
@business.placements.includes(:employee).group(:month).order('points DESC').map(&:employee)
```

But I get a PostgreSQL `group_by` error:

```
: SELECT "placements".* FROM "placements" INNER JOIN "employees" ON "placements"."employee_id" = "employees"."id" WHERE "employees"."business_id" = 43 GROUP BY month ORDER BY points DESC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "placements.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "placements".* FROM "placements" INNER JOIN "employee...
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you get an error, *always show the exact text of the error*. In this case, I think what you want is probably the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: If you don't add the "includes" in the statement, did the error still exist?

Comment: Yes I still get the error if I remove .includes(:employee)

Answer (score 0):

When you group any columns you select either need to be in the group_by or have some aggregation function on them. By default AR pulls back all the columns so you probably want to restrict that with a `.select`